# How can I make this combination logic more practical / compact?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

Context: I combined a NIMPLY gate and a NAND gate for inputs A and B. I am unable to create a working vertical/compact version of this combination logic.

I have provided an Imagine of the original circuit, my failed attempt at making it more compact and vertical, and a truth table it should follow:

| Input A | Input B | NIMPLY | NAND |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

The first input column is A, the second input column is B. The first output column is using NIMPLY (material nonimplication), the second output column is using NAND (sheffer-stroke).

Original circuit taking in inputs A and B and for outputs of NIMPLY and NAND:
[image: Original]

Failed attempt at compacting and making it vertical:
[image: Fail]